# dependent: :destroy doesn't work on has_one relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I delete child record so parent record does not get deleted automatically.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :agency, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :agency 
end

class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end

if @agency.present?
   @agency.user.destroy
   flash[:notice] = 'Agency Deleted'                  
end
```

Destroy child record so parent record automatically destroy.

Comment: The question is whether this is semantically correct... agency seems to be a higher hierarchy than the user, so shouldn't the `Agency` actually `have_one` (or probably even `has_many`) `User`s?

Comment: `@agency.user.destroy` implies that "user" is the child and "account" is the parent. In that case, the `belongs_to` and `has_one` should be switched, i.e. the user belongs to the agency, not the other way round. See the Rails Guides: [2.7 Choosing Between belongs_to and has_one](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one)

Answer (score 1):

I think, your models could be re-written like this to achieve expected output.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :agency # Change
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :agency 
end

class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy # Change
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end

if @agency.present?
   @agency.destroy # Change
   flash[:notice] = 'Agency Deleted'                  
end
```

Let's think logically now.

What have you changed is, you made `User` dependent on `Agency` and now it's rails doable to form a parent-child relationship to get accepted output. So when you destroy an `@agency`, it will also delete the dependent `user` record.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following code to delete a user and its associated agency **without making any change to your model.**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :agency, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :agency 
end

class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end

if @agency.present?
   user = @agency.user #Change
   user.destroy # This will destroy both user and associated agency.
   flash[:notice] = 'Agency and User Deleted'                  
end
```

A complete official guide on `dependent: :destroy` can be find [here.](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: Do you know why `@agency.user.destroy` doesn't work as expected?